# ¿Cómo actualizar una propiedad de un objeto embebido?

Tags: array, mongodb

¿Cómo puedo actualizar una propiedad en un documento incrustado? La estructura de mi documento es la siguiente:

```
{
  "_id": "5bfa09f0a0441f38d45dcc9c",
  "nombre": "PROYECTO MAIN",
  "area": "Sistemas",
  "fecha": "27/01/2018",
  "reuniones": [
    {
      "_id": "5bfa09f0a0441f38d45dcc99",
      "objetivo": "Objetivo MODIFICADO",
      "fecha": "25/10/2018",
      "participantes": [
        {
          "nomina": 1,
          "nombre": "MODIFICADO",
          "rol": "rol",
          "area": "area",
          "firma": "url/imagen.jpg"
        },
        {
          "nomina": 2,
          "nombre": "nombre 2",
          "rol": "rol",
          "area": "area",
          "firma": "url/imagen.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "_class": "proyecto"
}
```

### Progreso

Usando la siguiente consulta desde la consola de MongoDB, me devuelve el documento mencionado anteriormente.

```
 db.proyectos.find({
    _id:ObjectId("5bfa09f0a0441f38d45dcc9c"),
    "reuniones._id":ObjectId("5bfa09f0a0441f38d45dcc99"), 
    "reuniones.participantes.nomina":2 
 })
```

### Resultado esperado

Quiero actualizar el campo firma del participante con nomina 2.

Comment: es node con mongoose?

Comment: No @JackNavaRow, es Mongo directamente desde consola, después replicaré la query en Kotin.

Comment: en python 3.xxxx db.proyectos.update({"_id": ObjectId('5bfa09f0a0441f38d45dcc99')}, { '$set': {"reuniones.participantes":{"nomina": 1}}}) nota, todo lo que tenga dentro de participantes sera sustituido por solo `"nomina": 1`, yo ando buscando que algo que en vex de sustituirlo lo agrege.

Answer (score 0):

en python 3.xxxx

```
db.proyectos.update({"_id": ObjectId('5bfa09f0a0441f38d45dcc99')}, {
                  '$set': {"reuniones.participantes":{"nomina": 1}}})
```

nota, todo lo que tenga dentro de participantes sera sustituido por solo `"nomina": 1`, yo ando buscando que algo que en vex de sustituirlo lo agrege.

Answer (score -1):

Giban que lenguaje estas usando Python, JavaScript, Rubi o lo estas haciendo desde la consola de mongoDB?

en python sería algo como esto usando pymongo:

```
db.proyectos.update_one({
    '_id':'5bfa09f0a0441f38d45dcc9c',
    'reuniones._id':'5bfa09f0a0441f38d45dcc99', 
    'reuniones.0.participantes.1.nomina':2 
    }, {'$set': {'reuniones.0.participantes.1.firma': <DATO A ACTUALIZAR O MODIFICAR >})
```

Comment: Hola, estoy tratando primero de hacer la consulta en consola de Mongo y después la pienso replicar en Spring Boot y Kotlin.